# What type should I use for input react-bootstrap event with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap lib and need to use an input component. 
I know how to type a simple input but have a problem with `FormControl`

```
class Search extends Component<Props, { searchInput: string }> {

      static defaultProps = {}

      state = {
        searchInput: ""
      }

     // This one works for input 
      searchInputSimple = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
        const { getSearch } = this.props
        this.setState(
          { searchInput: e.currentTarget.value },
          (): void => getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
        )
      }

      // for FormControl. What can I use exept any?
      searchInput = (e: React.FormEvent<any>): void => {
        const { getSearch } = this.props
        this.setState(
          { searchInput: e.currentTarget.value },
          (): void => getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
        )
      }

      render() {
        const { searchInput } = this.state
        return (
          <>
            <InputGroup className="mb-3">
              <FormControl placeholder="Search" value={searchInput} onChange={this.searchInput} />
            </InputGroup>

            <input
              placeholder="Search"
              value={searchInput}
              onChange={this.searchInputSimple}
              className="form-control"
            />
          </>
        )
      }
    }
```

I tried to understand and look at `FormControl.d.ts`

```
import Feedback from './Feedback';

import { BsPrefixComponent } from './helpers';

interface FormControlProps {
  innerRef?: React.LegacyRef<this>;
  size?: 'sm' | 'lg';
  plaintext?: boolean;
  readOnly?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  value?: string;
  onChange?: React.FormEventHandler<this>;
  type?: string;
  id?: string;
  isValid?: boolean;
  isInvalid?: boolean;
}

declare class Form<
  As extends React.ReactType = 'input'
> extends BsPrefixComponent<As, FormControlProps> {
  static Feedback: typeof Feedback;
}
```

If I use just `HTMLInputElement` I'm getting this error

> Type error: Type '(e: FormEvent) => void' is not
>   assignable to type '(event: FormEvent & FormControlProps>>) => void'.   Types of
>   parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
>       Type 'FormEvent & FormControlProps>>' is not assignable to type
>   'FormEvent'.
>         Type 'Pick,
>   HTMLInputElement>, "children" | "form" | "style" | "title" | "pattern"
>   | "ref" | "key" | "defaultChecked" | ... 268 more ... | "width"> &
>   BsPrefixProps<...> & FormControlProps' is missing the following
>   properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': align, autocomplete,
>   autofocus, dirName, and 245 more.

So how to do it and not to use any type? Should it be an alias HTMLInputElement and something more?

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for a `React.ChangeEvent`, rather than a `React.FormEvent`:

```
searchInput = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    const { value } = e.currentTarget;
    const { getSearch } = this.props;
    this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        searchInput: value
    }), (): void => getSearch(this.state.searchInput))
}
```

Comment: I got almost the same error from FormControl onChange 'is not assignable to type '(event: FormEvent<ReplaceProps<"input", BsPrefixProps<"input"> & FormControlProps>>) => void''

Comment: OK, that's how we'd normally approach this from a standard Typescript/React point-of-view. Have you looked at the React Bootstrap documentation as your approach differs quite greatly. For example, you haven't defined the type of input as a prop: https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/forms/

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what are you asking. I just copied this textarea example https://ibb.co/Fs0Fyww pls have a look and got 'incompatible' error

Comment: I'm getting the same error as @victorzadorozhnyy: TS2322 (TS) Type '(e: FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: FormEvent<ReplaceProps<"input", BsPrefixProps<"input"> & FormControlProps>>) => void'.

Comment: It's pretty verbose, but changing the type of the input field to  'React.ChangeEvent<ReplaceProps<"input", BsPrefixProps<"input"> & FormControlProps>>' as per the error worked for me

Hope you can add to this answer as your main point solved the trouble I was having

Answer (score 4):

If you are using React.ChangeEvent this way

```
(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)
```

Please note that in your HTML code you should NOT call your function like this:

```
onChange={(e) => searchInput(e)}
```

Instead call it this way:

```
onChange={searchInput}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `any`, use `FormControl & FormControlProps`.

```
searchInput = (e: React.FormEvent<FormControl & FormControlProps>): void => {
  const { getSearch } = this.props
  this.setState(
    { searchInput: e.currentTarget.value as string},
    (): void => getSearch(this.state.searchInput)
  )
}
```

Taken from this [comment on the issue in @types/react-bootstrap](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16208#issuecomment-335993251).

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, but typing as `React.BaseSyntheticEvent` as suggested [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16208#issuecomment-639561967) did.